# How to change Eclipse's "associated source" for debugging?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have a jar file that supplies some classes in my development environment.  When I'm debugging in Eclipse, when I first step into a class supplied by that jar, Eclipse prompts me to give the location of the associated source files.  I do so, and everything's fine.

Some time later, I replace the jar with a newer version.  How can I instruct Eclipse to look in a different place for the newer source?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the Project Explorer (or Navigator), find the JAR (should be listed under "library path"), right-click, properties, there you can delete the association to a source, and/or provide a new association.

[image]

*Note: you must go to the properties for an individual JAR. You cannot get the equivalent dialog if you click on "JRE System Library"*

Comment: source jar file is not listed in library path

Answer (score 29):

Right click on the Debugger panel, select `Edit Source Lookup`

[image: Right click on the Debugger panel, select Edit Source Lookup]

Answer (score 4):

In the package explorer, where the jar is in a library (JRE, Maven dependencies, etc...); right click => properties => java source attachement.

Alternately in the project properties => Java build path => Library tab => select the jar => edit.